# Visual Basic : How to find a maximum and minimum in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

So, I have this project to work on for school, it's a statistics where I can enter the data and it spews out the points. The problem is I also have to find the player with the highest points and the lowest points. But I have no idea how to go through each line of the value and get the highest one and output it in the txtbox.I currently have the below code :

```
 Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    Dim playerName As String
    Dim jersey As Integer
    Dim assists As Integer
    Dim goals As Integer    'variables for the numerous things'
    Dim gamesWon As Integer
    Dim points As Integer = 0
    Dim lowestpoints As Integer
    Dim highestpoints As Integer



    'Enter Information here'

    playerName = InputBox("Enter the Player's Name: - end with x")

    jersey = InputBox("Enter the Jersey of the Player - end with -1")

    assists = InputBox("Enter the # of Assists of the Player - end with -1")

    goals = InputBox("Enter the # of Goals  - end with -1")

    gamesWon = InputBox("Enter the # of Games Won - end with a -1")

    'do while name is not "X" and "-1"

    While playerName <> "x" And jersey <> "-1" And assists <> "-1" And goals <> "-1" And gamesWon <> "-1"

        points = goals * 2 + assists
        'display the  stats'
        txtPlayerNames.Text = txtPlayerNames.Text + playerName + vbNewLine

        txtJerseys.Text = txtJerseys.Text + Str(jersey) + vbNewLine

        txtAssists.Text = txtAssists.Text + Str(assists) + vbNewLine

        txtGoals.Text = txtGoals.Text + Str(goals) + vbNewLine

        txtGamesWon.Text = txtGamesWon.Text + Str(gamesWon) + vbNewLine

        txtPoints.Text = txtPoints.Text + Str(points) + vbNewLine

        txtHighestPoints.Text = txtHighestPoints.Text + Str(highestpoints) + vbNewLine

        'ask user for playernames and stats - end the input with the name "X"
        playerName = InputBox("Enter the Player's Name: - end with x")

        jersey = InputBox("Enter the Jersey of the player - end with -1")

        assists = InputBox("Enter # of assists of the player - end with -1")

        goals = InputBox("Enter the # of Goals - end with -1")

        gamesWon = InputBox("Enter the # of Games Won - end with -1")
        'ask for players names and stats and ends with -1' 'if not equal to these integers it exits the loop.

        If playerName = "x" Or jersey = "-1" Or assists = "-1" Or goals = "-1" Or gamesWon = "-1" Then
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
```

Comment: From where do you want to get the minimum or maximum values ?

Comment: From tjhe points sorry didnt specify

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's no way your code will work for multiple data and neither for storing the data. What you need to do is create a class for the variables separately.

```
Public Class Players
Public playerName As String
Public jersey As Integer
Public assists As Integer
Public goals As Integer    'variables for the numerous things'
Public gamesWon As Integer
Public points As Integer = 0
Public lowestpoints As Integer
Public highestpoints As Integer
```

Then you need to create a `List` of the class in your main class(Make sure to create it in class level).

```
Public Class MainClass
Dim PlayerList as New List(of Players)
```

Then you need create a new instance of the class every time you need to save the data of. Consider the blow code for storing the information :

```
Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click

Dim newPlayer as New Players
newplayer.PlayerName = "abc"
''''pass values to other required variables
playerList.Add(newPlayer)
End sub
```

Now, you have a list of all the players. It is time to get the player details with maximum points :

```
Dim maxPoint = PlayerList.Max(Function(point) point.points)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks guys ill try it sorry im just new to coding so idk much.

Comment: Ideally, that would be `Public Class Player`, i.e. singular, because an instance of that class is for *one* player.

Comment: Public fields? The OOP gods will punish you for violating encapsulation.